# sed/find/grep append c# comment to top of file if not there, and replace if exists

Tags: sed, grep

I have a copyright clause I want to append to the top of a bunch of files in a directory as a comment (C#). It is to look like this:

```
/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/
/*C Use, duplication, or disclosure of this software and        T*/
/*C related documentation is blah blah blah blah                T*/
/*C Copyright 2004 - 2018 COMPANY                               T*/
/*C All rights reserved.                                        T*/
/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/
```

Some of the files contain a clause already, but with the 2017 or 2016 date, I want to make sure the date in the clause is set to 2018. And if there isn't any  clause, I want to insert one.

So far I have implemented `find` to only modify the files I need in the directory:

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" \) -print0
```

Because this clause is to be a comment at the top of each file, it starts and ends with `/*...*/`. I tried using `sed` but it is tricky since the slashes and asterisks are used for other things in `sed`. 
Here is my `find` and `sed` combined. This replaces all instances of 2017 with 2018 and appends the clause but it appends it even if its already there. I only need it to append if it's not there.

```
find ....... -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/2004 - 2017/2004 - 2018/g; 1s/^/\/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*\/\n\/*C Use, duplication, or disclosure of this software and.....etc'
```

Is there a better way of doing this in grep or sed? Thanks
EDIT: I AM USING CYGWIN

Answer (score 0):

grep is for `g/re/p`  and sed is for `s/old/new` on individual lines so neither tool is appropriate for your problem.

This should do what you want using GNU awk (which you have on cygwin) for inplace editing:

```
find ... -exec awk -i inplace '
FNR==1 {
    print "/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/"
    print "/*C Use, duplication, or disclosure of this software and        T*/"
    print "/*C related documentation is blah blah blah blah                T*/"
    print "/*C Copyright 2004 - 2018 COMPANY                               T*/"
    print "/*C All rights reserved.                                        T*/"
    print "/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/"

    if ( /COPYRIGHT/ ) { inCopy=1 }
    next
}
inCopy && /COPYRIGHT/ { inCopy=0 }
!inCopy
' {} +
```

If an old copyright block is already present at the start of the file it just replaces the whole block with the new one. You can change each `/COPYRIGHT/` to `index($0,"/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/")` if you want more precise matching on that text to indicate the start and end of the comment block.

Comment: i had to remove the `inCopy && /COPYRIGHT/..` because it was appending a closing copyright line to the end of the block every time i ran the script, even if it already had one. otherwise worked beautifully! what does inCopy mean?

Comment: That line is required or youll delete every line of your input when there's an existing copyright block and it's not possible for that to happen given the code I posted, you must have done something wrong when you copy/pasted.  `inCopy` is just a variable I created to indicate we're in the copyright block.

Comment: could it have something to do with my find operations? or that i'm using cygwin? i copied and pasted exactly

Comment: No. If you had provided sample input and expected output in your question then we could have tested our proposed solutions but as-is - idk, my code looks right to me.

Comment: i did provide an expected output, it's the first code block in my question. That's exactly what should appear at the top of a file after the script was run. As for input.. I provided what I had of the script I was writing. Thats the only 'input' i guess

Comment: No, that's not the expected output, that's a block of text you want included in your output. Sample input is, say, 5 lines of some truly representative file before your desired tool runs and expected output would be that same file with that block of text included (or not as appropriate). In your case you should have at least 2 sample input/outputs - one example with no copyright previously present and one with it previously present but with the date needing to be updated. If you don't provide something we can test against to prove if a script works or not then obviously we can't do that.

Comment: See [ask] and pay particular attention to the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: ahh im sorry i thought input and output was something different!!! another thing i've noticed is if i have one of the files that is being edited opened while i run the script, everything but the copyright clause is deleted. however, if i dont open the file as the script runs, only the clause changes. I made sure my code was exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with whatever tool it is you use to "open" your file while the tool is running. What you describe simply will not happen when using UNIX tools unless you manually do something to make it happen (no, I've no idea what that might be).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
find ... -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    if [[ $(head -1 "$f") = "/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/" ]]; then
        sed -i 's/2004 - 2017/2004 - 2018/g' "$f"
    else
        sed -i '1s#^#/*COPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHTCOPYRIGHT*/\n/*C Use, duplication, or disclosure of this software and.....etc */\n#' "$f"
    fi
done
```

It passes the result of `find` not to `xargs` but to the `while` loop and switches the processing depending of the first line of the file.

Comment: Tha would replace `2004 - 2017` with `2004 - 2018` **anywhere** in the file, not just in the copyright comment block.